# Modify learning rate in imported Tensorflow graph

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have created a graph with an AdamOptimizer, which I have then saved with `tf.train.Saver().save(session, "model_name")`

After training it for a while I am able to import the whole graph and the variables in a different session and resume training with

```
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("model_name")
saver.restore(session, "model_name")
```

What I would like to do is, after importing the graph+variables and before resuming the optimization, to change the `learning_rate` of the AdamOptimizer. Is that possible?

EDIT: One way of doing this would be to define the learning rate as a placeholder and feed a different value every time. But let's assume the graph has already been saved without doing this for the sake of argument.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can replace learning_rate with placeholder,ie.

```
learning_rate = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(),name="learing_rate")
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(your_loss_tensor, name="train_op")
```

when you have restored your graph, get all the all ops and tensors that related to train like `train_op` and `learning_rate` using

```
train_op = graph.get_operation_by_name("train_op")
learning_rate = graph.get_tensor_by_name("learning_rate:0")
```

and run train

```
sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={learning_rate: whatever_you_what})
```

UPDATE:
see [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1758) if you want to change some input of your saved graph

Comment: That would indeed work, but as I mentioned in my edit I'm interested in how it would be done if the graph had already been saved. I guess my question can be generalised to: how can you modify a graph after saving and importing it?